# Watir with webdriver, proxy, Firefox

Tags: firefox, proxy, watir, webdriver

I am able to use watir-webdriver with IE, but I would prefer to use Firefox.
Problem: I need a proxy.
By googling around, I found some code snippets, but I am not able to put all them together.
This is what I produced up to now, please let me know what am I missing:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "proxy.myplace.com");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 8080);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto( "http://www.google.com/" )
```

I get this error message:

```
I:/watir/webdriver/webdrivertest.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expec
ting keyword_do or '{' or '('
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
```

Also, I don't know how to use the variable called 'driver'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the underlying Selenium WebDriver.

I've used this technique to set a path to Firefox 3.6 so I can test with both Firefox 4 and 3.6:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = ENV['FIREWATIRPATH']
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

So to do what you're trying to do:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(:http => "http://proxy.org:8080")
profile.proxy = proxy

# You have to do a little more to use the specific profile
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
browser = Watir::Browser.new(driver)
```

Look at: [Selenium Ruby Bindings](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings) and [Webdriver FAQ](https://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver/wiki/FAQ) for more info.

---

What problem are you having with the Proxy line?

You could try [this](http://blog.chrislowis.co.uk/2010/07/14/http-proxy-selenium-webdriver-and-firefox.html):

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile["network.proxy.type"] = 1
profile["network.proxy.http"] = "proxy.myplace.com"
profile["network.proxy.http_port"] = 8080
```

The idea is to see what your settings are in about:config and duplicating them in code.

Comment: It seems we are close.
There is a problem in this line:

proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(:http => "http://proxy.myplace.org:8080")

The error message is invalid value for Integer(): "//proxy.unv.org:8080"

This means it is interpreting anything after the first : as a port number. Maybe I should enter the http in another format?

Comment: Also, if I skip the http:// part, and enter the proxy as "proxy.myplace.com:8080" the script runs, but Firefox does not get the proxy setting, and therefore cannot run

Comment: I bet you could do Proxy.new(:http => 'proxy.org', :http_port => '8080')

Comment: Nope...Proxy doesn't have http_port as an option

Comment: This seems to work.

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile["network.proxy.type"] = 1
profile["network.proxy.http"] = "proxy.myplace.com"
profile["network.proxy.http_port"] = 8080

Comment: Doing `Proxy.new(:http => "proxy.myplace.com:8080")` is correct and works well for me.

Comment: Proxy.new(:http => "proxy.myplace.com:8080") is actually correct, but it did not work with my configuration.
The solution for me was to set the proxy setting to autodetect:

profile["network.proxy.type"] = 4

By doing this, we don't even need to specify proxy address and port

Answer (score 4):

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new :http => '12.12.12.12:8888', :ssl => '15.15.15.15:443'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

Answer (score 2):

The base problem in your original question is right in the error message

```
webdrivertest.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

The ruby interpreter is seeing something on the third line of your script that looks like a constant, in a place it's expecting something else.

I suspect it's the start of the line where ruby expects a variable name, and you have a classname.  Ruby expects variables named starting with an uppercase to be a constant.  which is fine for defining a class, but not creating an instance of one, since the instance won't be a constant.

It also looks like you are trying to do a new invocation using a 'new' keyword ala some other language, instead of using a .new  method on whatever object you want to make a new one of, the ruby way.

Compare the code in the answer by Mike  where he does

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
```

verses what you were trying to do on line 3

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
```

See how different they are?  His is the way to do it.

Comment: Well said.  Solving the .new problem probably would have led down a slightly different path.