# Watir-webdriver can't access 127.0.0.1

Tags: selenium, proxy, selenium-webdriver, watir

I receive a "Gateway Timeout" error when running the following ruby code using `watir-webdriver`.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
```

The error states:

> Server error - server 127.0.0.1 is unreachable at this moment.
> Please retry the request or contact your adminstrator.

I have a feeling the company proxy is interfering with Watir. Maybe Firefox is trying to connect to Watir running locally on some non-standard port, and the proxy intervenes and can't resolve the address 127.0.0.1. That's just a guess.

Anyone have experience with this error or suggestions for getting `watir-webdriver` working. Has anyone successfully run `watir-webdriver` behind a proxy?

Here is the error with stack trace:

> 504 Gateway Timeout
>
> ## Gateway Timeout
>
> Server error - server 127.0.0.1 is
>   unreachable at this moment.
> Please retry the request or contact
>   your admins trator.
>
> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:66:in
>   `create
>   _response' C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in`
>   reque st'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in
>   `call'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:640:in`
>   raw_execut e'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:101:in
>   `create_ses sion'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in`
>   initialize'
>
> C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:36:in
>   `initialize '
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in`
>   new'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in
>   `for'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in`
>   for'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize' c:/dev/pxmapper/features/support/env.rb:11:in`new'
>   c:/dev/pxmapper/features/support/env.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in`
>   load'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in
>   `load_code_file'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in`load_file'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in
>   `block in load_files!'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in`
>   each'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in
>   `load_files!'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in`
>   load_step_definitions'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in
>   `run!'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in`
>   execute!'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/bin/cucumber:13:in
>   `<top (required)>' C:/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in`load'
>   C:/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in `'

Comment: You could also reference to this answer for watir-webdriver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431232/watir-with-webdriver-proxy-firefox; add network.proxy.no_proxies_on for 127.0.0.1

Comment: Umm...try "http://localhost"